# How to get unique rpcpassword for bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

I am on Linux Debian 8.4 and have one server running 24/7.
I would like to help the Bitcoin network.

On https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions I got to the point where I should run `bitcoind` and it should give me unique password:

> Then you can run the command `bitcoind`. It will print output similar to this:

But it does not print out anything. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Bitcoin Core 0.12, an RPC password is no longer required for normal operation. Instead, a random password is automatically generated by `bitcoind` and stored in a temporary file on disk. When an RPC client (like `bitcoin-cli`) wants to connect, it automatically uses the password from this file.

Comment: Remember to specify the `-datadir` on the `bitcoin-cli` command line if it isn't the default.  Otherwise the cookie file won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a bitcoin.conf file in place it will not generate a password, backup your current config file and try again.